# Different "Read more" in different excerpts on the same page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want two differents excerpts on my homepage, one for the posts inside the loop, the other one for the latest post published, outside the loop.

I managed to add the excerpt on the latest post outside of the loop like this

```
<?php $postslist = get_posts('numberposts=1&order=DESC&orderby=post_date');
                                foreach ($postslist as $post) :
                                setup_postdata($post); ?>
<?php wp_latest_excerpt('wp_latest', 'excerpt_more_latest'); ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

While the excerpt for the posts inside the loop is

```
 <?php wp_excerpt('wp_index'); ?>
```

For some reasons I am able to set the excerpt length differently for both of my excerpts, but the "more" stays the same. (both "more" have the class `.view-article`)
I thought I could create another excerpt with a different "more" function, but it does not work, here are my 2 different excerpts and more functions.

For the length

```
function wp_index($length) 
{
return 21;
}


function wp_latest($length) 
{
return 18;
}
```

For the "more"

```
function view_article($more)
{
return '... </br><a class="view-article" href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . __('Continue Reading', '') . '</a>';
}

function latest_view_article($more)
{
return '... </br><a class="view-latest-article" href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . __('Continue Reading', '') . '</a>';
}

add_filter('excerpt_more_latest', 'latest_view_article'); 
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'view_article');
```

And finally the excerpts

```
function wp_latest_excerpt($length_callback = '', $more_callback = '')
{
if (function_exists($length_callback)) {
    add_filter('excerpt_length', $length_callback);
}
if (function_exists($more_callback)) {
    add_filter('excerpt_more_latest', $more_callback);
}
$output = get_the_excerpt();
$output = apply_filters('wptexturize', $output);
$output = apply_filters('convert_chars', $output);
$output = '<p>' . $output . '</p>';
echo $output;
}

function wp_excerpt($length_callback = '', $more_callback = '')
{
if (function_exists($length_callback)) {
    add_filter('excerpt_length', $length_callback);
}
if (function_exists($more_callback)) {
    add_filter('excerpt_more', $more_callback);
}
$output = get_the_excerpt();
$output = apply_filters('wptexturize', $output);
$output = apply_filters('convert_chars', $output);
$output = '<p>' . $output . '</p>';
echo $output;
}
```

Is this a wrong way to achieve this or did I make some mistakes in my code ?

Comment: First get rid of global and the hard coded function with the magic numbers. Use constants.

Comment: Are you refering to the function for the length ?

Comment: Yes I am refering to that